# Crashing when switching between aplication

Tags: unity, launcher, menu, application-switcher

When I have multiple instances of any application like file manager and I want to switch between them by clicking on the application the system crashes.
 The first time the system is stopping and throw an internal error but the second time the menu and the launcher disappears.

The Alt-Tab shortcut working fine, just when I click by mouse in the application that has multi-page it crashes.

The super + w shortcut has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I Found The Solution.
I tried several ways to fix this problem and when i rebooted my system i saw my ubuntu is working safely.
i think the solution is this:

1-open unity-tweak-tool(if it's installed).

2-open all pages and tabs and click restore to default in all of them.

3-reboot your system.

please write your feedback because i'm not sure.

Comment: هادی جان سلام دوست عزیز من اوبونتو رو دوباره نصب کردم البته به خاطر تست کردن اوبونتو استدیو و اوبونتو جنومِ

Comment: درسته.من هم نمی دونم دیروز چطور درست شد این مشکل.شاید به خاطر آپدیت های جدید درست شده.